# (C++) list.error method and deleting memory using pointer

Tags: c++, list, pointers, erase

```
typedef struct  value 
{
    char* contents;
    int size;
}Value;

hash_map<Key,list<Value>,hash<Key>,eqKey> dspace;
list<Value> vallist;
```

.

what i am doing every time i am creating a  `Value` variable and adding to this list.

I have a pointer `Value * ptr` and i am using this pointer to point to a member of the list and finally I am erasing the member from the list.

Now i can access the value using pointer but not using the list iterator.

I have two questions

1. does erase remove the element from the list but the allocated memory remains unchanged or is the memory is also being freed .
2. Is it possible to free the memory using this ptr. or if i set the ptr to some other member of the list then the memory occupied by the previous member will be freed or not.

Comment: Basic rule of C++: Things don't just happen magically. If something happens, you know that it does and why it does so. If you didn't request it, it probably isn't happening. The C-programmer's rule of C++: don't typedef your structs. The beginner's C++ rule: Use `std::string`.

Comment: When you erase a member, it is gone, and your pointer is invalid. If you want to keep a value, you have to make a copy.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of a hashmap whose mapped type is a list, perhaps an `unordered_multimap` would also do the trick? You wouldn't have the sequential ordering within elements with the same type, but it would be less complex and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. The element ceases to exist. If the element was a pointer, then the pointer ceases to exist but the object it pointed to is unaffected. The element itself, however, is gone. Otherwise, lists would be extremely difficult to use.
2. What you do with pointers has no effect on the list at all. If you want pointers the keep objects alive such that the object is destroyed when, and only when, the last pointer to it is destroyed, you can use those. (Such as Boost's `shared_ptr`.)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `dspace.erase()` to remove an element from your hashmap, the memory used is freed. This means that the memory is now available to be used for other things. It does **not** mean that the data in that block of memory is erased. When you try to access the data via a pointer, it may appear that the memory is still intact, which is perhaps why you are asking if the memory has been freed. However, doing so will result in undefined behavior since the memory to which your pointer points may be reused at any time.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please click the check mark to accept it. Also, you may vote on any answers by clicking the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you erase the `Value` instance from the list, its allocated memory is freed.
2. Generally one would call `delete ptr;` but this won't work in your case, as the memory for the instance is freed already. Changing the value of a normal pointer has no effect on memory allocation at all.

Your `Value`has a `char *contents` member. The memory it is pointing to may be leaked if a `Value` instance is deleted - depending on how you allocated it. You should consider using a std::string instead.